# Camel Ip Address caching

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a URL in camel route which is set via JVM custom property and it remains unchanged.

```
    **<camel:to id="to-server" uri="{{serverURL}}" />**
```

serverURL property is set to a site loadbalancer address http://xyz:8080/Server/transactionServlet

In the network layer this URL can either be pointed to Server 1 or Server 2, the URL should work regardless of which server we're using.

After the switch over from Server 1 to Server 2, our WAR still tries to post to Server 1 and fails.
It appears that our WAR is caching the the URL address (what the site loadbalancer was pointing to at the time) when it was started and does not recognize that we have switched over.
The only workaround is to restart the application WAR, at which point it stores the Server 2 address (what the site loadbalancer is now pointing to) and begins posting transactions to Server 2.

is there any way to make camel not cache the IP Address and post to whatever server URL is pointing to ?
I am using Apache Camel 2.14

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`networkaddress.cache.ttl`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html).

> Specified in java.security to indicate the caching policy for successful name lookups from the name service.. The value is specified as integer to indicate the number of seconds to cache the successful lookup.
>   A value of -1 indicates "cache forever". The default behavior is to cache forever when a security manager is installed, and to cache for an implementation specific period of time, when a security manager is not installed.

Comment: Please elaborate. provide examples and code snippets.

Comment: I'm sorry, the rest of my post doesn't seem to be there ...  Please see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html.  The underlying Java JDK caches the DNS to IP address values.

Comment: I have fixed link in your answer and added quote to linked documentation.